# How to make sure a Kafka consumer instance get's all the logs that it cares about?

Tags: apache-kafka, graphql

If you have a kafka topic broken up into partitions. Let's just say 2 to keep this simple, `partition_0` and `partition_1` (but in reality it would be much more)

Now let's say we have a consumer that is a GraphQL subscription running on a node app, and let's say there are 2 instances/pods of this running `instance_A` and `instance_B` (in reality it could be much more)

Since they are instances of the same app, just scaling into more than one instance, they should be using the same group id. From my understanding, this would mean that each instance will only be consuming from a single partition:

```
[instance_A] <---- consuming --- [parition_0]
[instance_B] <---- consuming --- [parition_1]
```

Well when a user makes a graphql subscription, they are going to be randomly connecting to a single instance and have a connection kept open via sockets.

This instance will only be connecting to a single partition, what if the events the user cares about (is subscribed to) are actually on a different partition?

One idea is to just give each instance it's own unique group id, so each instance get's all logs... but that sounds like it wouldn't scale?

Is there a pattern for this that I am missing? Am I just thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A piece of info you might not have considered is using the key, every message with the same key ends up on the same partition. e.g. key1 --> partition1 this can help with your design.

What you're talking about with the instances sharing the same groupId is called a consumer group.

So for your problem it sounds like you could determine the key the consumer needs and have it subscribe to that, which would only be 1 partition of interest.